# inet address not being assigned in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, network-interface

I am running raspbian and have plugged in two wifi usb dongles.

In my */etc/network/interfaces* I have assigned them both ip address.

```
...
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

iface default inet dhcp

iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
...
```

When I run *ifconfig -a* I can see that **wlan0** is receiving an IP but **wlan1** isnt.

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:11:01:11:11:12
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:10000 (9.7 KiB)  TX bytes:576 (576.0 B)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:11:94:22:22
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I have also noticed that **wlan0** appears to have been assigned the address which specified **wlan1** should have in */etc/network/interfaces*

I have tried rebooting, problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

The line `iface default inet dhcp` tells the WPA Supplicant to configure and activate each *default* network with DHCP upon a successful connection to an access point. See https://wiki.debian.org/WPA

Your definitions for `wlan0` and `wlan1` expect static addresses. But you've just overridden that with DHCP.

If you know the WiFi details for the networks to which `wlan0` and `wlan1` are to connect then you should remove the `default` line and define the networks directly. See [the `wpasupplicant` `README.Debian`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/wpa/blob/debian/master/debian/wpasupplicant.README.Debian) for an example:

```
iface wlan0 inet static
        wpa-ssid HotSpot1
        # plaintext passphrase
        wpa-psk madhotspot
        wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
        wpa-pairwise TKIP CCMP
        wpa-group TKIP CCMP
        wpa-proto WPA RSN
        # static ip settings
        address 192.168.2.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```